# What is a web application client id for Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to get the sample [android client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android#language) to work.

I am stuck on step 4 of the setup instructions:

> Update the value of AUDIENCE in src/com/google/devrel/samples/ttt/ClientCredentials.java, replacing the string "your_web_client_id" with the web application client ID you registered in the APIs Console.

Here's the line of code I need to change:

```
public static final String AUDIENCE = "server:client_id:your_web_client_id";
```

I am not sure what they mean by "web application client ID".  I have the Java backend up and running on GAE, but haven't done anything with the APIs Console.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

Here's the client id code for the java backend:

```
/**
 * Contains the client IDs for allowed clients consuming the tictactoe API.
 */
public class Ids {
  public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "240003018828.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  public static final String ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = "240003018828-rp5ahj5b1eo76g55m1qtq4vvm57dqoj6.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  public static final String IOS_CLIENT_ID = "replace this with your iOS client ID";
  public static final String ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID;
}
```

And here's the client id code in the android project:

```
public class ClientCredentials
{
    public static final String AUDIENCE = "server:client_id:240003018828-rp5ahj5b1eo76g55m1qtq4vvm57dqoj6.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    // public static final String AUDIENCE = "server:client_id:your_web_client_id";
}
```

And also from the android project:

```
  /**
   * The default encoded root URL of the service. This is determined when the library is generated
   * and normally should not be changed.
   *
   * @since 1.7
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "https://sample-ttt.appspot.com/_ah/api/";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Making Authenticated Calls](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making-authenticated-calls) portion of the Endpoints documentation for Android.

> Add a second client ID in the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) for your project. To
>   do this:
>
> 1. In the API Access tab for your project inside the console, click Create another client ID.
> 2. List item
> 3. In the Create Client ID form, select Installed application for the application type, and Android for the installed application type.
> 4. In the textbox labeled Package name enter your Android application package name.
> 5. In the textbox labeled Signing certificate fingerprint, enter the debug or release key that you just generated.
> 6. Click Create client ID.

It speaks of a second client ID because you'll also need to create one for a web application. At the end of the process you should have two client IDs: one for Android, one for the web. You use both client IDs in your backend code, but only include the latter client ID (via the specially formatted string) in your Android code.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Does that mean I need to have a project in the API Console?  Because right now I just have the java backend project, and the android client project, both form github.

Comment: Yes, you should create a project in the API Console.

Comment: Alright, I've created the two client ids and put them in the projects.  Now when I get an GoogleAuthIOException when the android tries to connect to the java backend.  Does that mean I've got one of the ids wrong?  Do I need to make some services active for my project in the APIs Console?

Comment: The backend requires configuration as well. Did you update the Java backend with the client IDs you registered? If you did, did you redeploy it as well?

Comment: I think so.  In the Java backend I added the webclient id and the android id.  In the android client I added the webclient id.  I just redeployed (stopped old backend, restarted, renavigated to http://localhost:8888/) and same problem.  Do I need an implementation for the web client?

Comment: No. If you could update your question with the current state of your code, it might be easier to debug.

Comment: Good idea, one last thing before I do that, I just checked my GAE Applications Overview, and for under "Current Version" it says "None Deployed".  Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, you should deploy your code and point your Android application to the deployed version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24797/discussion-between-nissemand-and-dan-holevoet)

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated the AUDIENCE field in your app engine backend with the web application id? For consuming GCE from Android client, you need update the Audience field also in your @Api annotation, with web application id (not android client id), you had registered in APIs console.